# Bash: bad array subscript

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

```
threads=`ls t[0-9][0-9]`       

for thread in "${threads[@]}"
do
       echo $thread
done
```

Expected result:

```
t01
t02
t10
```

Actual Result:

```
threads[@]: bad array subscript
```

Comment: Also, you might want to actually ask a question instead of just putting up code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying:

```
threads=`ls t[0-9][0-9]`
```

or

```
threads=\`ls t[0-9][0-9]\`
```

**does not** create an array.

In order to create an array, say:

```
threads=(ls t[0-9][0-9])
```

Moreover, [avoid parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).