# bash: Bash: bad array subscript

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

```
 table_list=`grep t_ sql.out | awk '{print $1}'`
 echo $table_list
 #t_acct_adj t_assc_fop t_cpn_dup_use t_cpn_upfront_pexp
 
 for table in "${table_list[@]}"
 do
     echo $table
 done
```

**Expected result:**

t_acct_adj

t_assc_fop

t_cpn_dup_use

t_cpn_upfront_pexp

**Actual Result:**

bad array subscript

Comment: What did you learn from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400180/bash-bad-array-subscript)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To store the results into an array, you need to use the `var=( values )` syntax, or in this case `var=( $(command output) )`:

```
table_list=($(grep t_ sql.out | awk '{print $1}'))
```

You can also make this `grep | awk` just with `awk`. For that, check [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21401769/1983854).

#### Example

```
$ cat a
hello
bye
hello2

$ values=($(grep hello a))

$ for v in "${values[@]}"; do echo "$value"; echo "aa"; done
hello
aa
hello2
aa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all of your scripts with this single line awk:

```
awk '/t_/ {print $1}' sql.out
```